# ¿Como crear un evento con google calendar api en proyecto ASP .NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, google-calendar

mi problema es que yo segui la guia de https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet
 (Sección .NET) y depurando del visual studio me funciona perfecto. pero cuando lo hosteaba en mi servidor en IIS. dejaba de funcionar. Googleando llegue a ver que muchos de los que tenian mi problema usaban otro tipo de autenticacion como la siguiente:

```
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });
```

como no pude implementar esta solucion mi codigo sigue igual que al principio.

```
  [Services(ServicesExecutionMode.Command)]
        public void SaveAuthorization(AuthorizationDto authorizationDto)
        {
            var entity = this._vacationRepository.GetById(authorizationDto.EntityId.Value);
            entity.Authorized = authorizationDto.Authorize;
            entity.AuthorizedDate = DateTime.Now;
            entity.AuthorizerId = CurrentId;

            this._vacationRepository.Persist(entity);

            string auth = "rechazada";
            if (authorizationDto.Authorize)
            {
                InsertCalendarEvent(entity);
                auth = "aceptada";
            }

            Account account = _accountRepository.GetById(entity.AccountId);

            string days = "desde el día " + entity.DateFrom.ToShortDateString() + " hasta el día " + entity.DateTo.ToShortDateString();

            if (entity.DateFrom == entity.DateTo)
                days = "el día " + entity.DateFrom.ToShortDateString();

            _mailService.SendMail("Tu solicitud de vacaciones fue " + auth, account.Name + " tu solicitud de vacaciones " + days + " fue " + auth + ".", account.Mail);
        }
```

Metodo que inserta el calendario:

```
 private void InsertCalendarEvent(Vacation vacation)
        {
            string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
            string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
               new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            var ev = new Event();
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
            start.DateTime = vacation.DateFrom;

            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
            end.DateTime = vacation.DateTo;

            ev.Start = start;
            ev.End = end;
            ev.Summary = vacation.Account.GetFullName() + " - Vacación";
            ev.Description = "Días consumidos: " + vacation.ConsumedDays.ToString();

            var calendarId = "primary";
            Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarId).Execute();
        }
 }
```

Intente ver algunos ejemplo de como implementar esto pero resulta que tampoco me sirvió porque es para projectos asp.net y el mio es .Net core. y no logre encontrar nadie que me muestre un ejemplo de como implementarlo para mi proyecto. Lo único que necesito es poder insertar eventos en un calendario en mi proyecto. Por favor si alguien me puede enviar un ejemplo me seria de gran ayuda. Gracias!
Encontre una persona que tiene el mismo problema quizas se explica mejor que yo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842813/google-calendar-api-working-fine-locally-but-not-raising-its-authentication-on-s-s)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca todo el código que has intentado para que la comunidad pueda reproducir tu caso. Saludos

Comment: @fredyfx ahi puse mi código actual. pero básicamente es el que no funciona para aplicaciones web, no creo que sea de ayuda. ya que mi problema no es un error o un bug, si no mas bien no se como implementar la api de google calendar para un proyecto ASP .NET CORE

Comment: @OctavioVillalón ¿ha consultado la documentación para ver si existe ejemplos con C#? - puede buscar también publicaciones en Stack Overflow (*en inglés*) - para ver si alguien mas ha publicado una pregunta similar.

Comment: con esta doc no te funciona? https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Si he buscado en todas partes y no encuentro una solucion.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Ramiro esa docuemntacion fue la primera que tomé y me funciona localmente pero cuando lo hosteo en mi servidor IIS deja de funcionar. y al final de esa docs dice lo siguiente: 
The authorization flow in this example is designed for a command-line application. For information on how to perform authorization in a web application, see the web applications section of the library's OAuth 2.0 guide.
Lo que me lleva a https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc . pero mi proyecto es NET CORE MVC y no tengo la ref System.Web.Mvc

Comment: y no te permite instalarla por Nuget Package?

Answer (score 0):

ese código es para app de escritorio
este es para web
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/351954)